# Go resetting closure variable

Tags: go, closures, anonymous-function

I came upon an example of closures in Go here:
https://gobyexample.com/closures

It gives a pretty straight-forward example of closure scoping in Go. I changed how i is initialized from "i := 0" to "i := *new(int)".

```
func intSeq() func() int {
    i := *new(int)
    return func() int {
        i += 1
        return i
    }
}

func main() {

    // We call `intSeq`, assigning the result (a function)
    // to `nextInt`. This function value captures its
    // own `i` value, which will be updated each time
    // we call `nextInt`.
    nextInt := intSeq()

    // See the effect of the closure by calling `nextInt`
    // a few times.
    fmt.Println(nextInt())
    fmt.Println(nextInt())
    fmt.Println(nextInt())

    // To confirm that the state is unique to that
    // particular function, create and test a new one.
    newInts := intSeq()
    fmt.Println(newInts())
}
```

The output of this is still 1, 2, 3, 1. Does the variable 'i' in intSeq() not get reallocated everytime nextInt() in main() is called?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at how you implemented `intSeq`.

```
func intSeq() func() int {
    i := *new(int)
    return func() int {
        i += 1
        return i
    }
}
```

The initialization of `i` is outside of the function it returns.

So the only time a new pointer is allocated is when you actually call `intSeq`.

Since you are doing that just two times, that's how many different pointers you got.

That explains why the value is not reset when you just call `nextInt` (note that executing `nextInt` means just executing the function returned, which looks like:

```
func() int {
   i += 1
   return i
}
```

That would not reset the value of `i` but rather keep incrementing it (until you create a new one by calling `intSeq` again).

I hope that clarifies.

Answer (score 2):

No it doesn't. That's the point of the closure. You are initializing an integer variable and storing it on the heap for use by the function the `intSeq()` function returns. There is no variable initialization happening in the `nextInt()` function

You will get a new function that uses a new sequence counter starting at 0 for each call to `intSeq()`

Edit: to add to this this is a bad way to get the current behavior. A better way would be to create a new `sequence` type that contains the method `nextInt() int`. E.g.:

```
type Sequence struct {
    counter int
}

func (s *Sequence) nextInt() int {
    s.counter++
    return s.counter
}

func main() {
    intSeq := new(Sequence)
    fmt.Println(intSeq.nextInt())
    fmt.Println(intSeq.nextInt())
    fmt.Println(intSeq.nextInt())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in doing `i := *new(int)`. That line says:

1. Allocate a new `int`
2. Create a pointer to it
3. Dereference the pointer
4. Assign the value to `i`

This is no different from `i := 0` or `var int i`, but there's the extra step in the middle of creating, dereferencing, and discarding the pointer that never gets used.

If you want a pointer to an int, use `i := new(int)`. `*new` anywhere is a pointless invocation and a code smell.

Comment: Agreed. As much as I'd like to upvote this, it isn't technically an answer to the question, so I'll have to stick with a positive comment ;)